# Can not input value into text field which use sx:datetimepicker

Tags: java, struts

I have problem when I use `sx:datetimepicker` tag, with lib: `struts2-dojo-plugin-2.2.3.1.jar`. This is the source code:

```
<sx:datetimepicker name="info.date1" id="date1" displayFormat="yyyyMMdd HHmmss" cssStyle="font-size:13.5px" />
```

I input the value from calendar, it runs normally. But I input value into `date1` field using the keyboard (not using the calendar) and then move focus to other element, and that value is lost. Thus I cannot input the value by hand.

---

I have to meet two problems: 
1. Lost data when i input by hand into textbox(using sx:datetimepicker tag). It happens when i  move focus to other item.
2. I need date with full format(yyyyMMdd HHmmss). It only displays date part and not including time part(example: 20111201 000000).

These errors happen with struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.6.jar and struts2-dojo-plugin-2.3.1.jar

Currently, i can not resolve two problems.
Please help me.

Comment: Are you writing date in same format as it takes when you enter from sx:datetimepicker ?

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
 displayFormat="yyyyMMdd HHmmss"
```

you will get value as 20111201 000000.

Using `"yyyyMMdd HHmmss"` as date format enter date with a space and `000000`
but i dont think 000000 can be useful

I suggest using

```
<sx:datetimepicker name="info.date1" id="date1"  displayFormat="dd-MM-yyyy" required="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. But i use "yyyyMMdd HHmmss" because i need to output full date, including: date, hour, minutes, seconds. Could you suggest me use other tool to get full date?